# Aggregate pipeline returns wrong result vs CLI

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a collection in mongo on which I run the following query

```
db.feeds.aggregate({"$match":{createdat:"20190203"}}, {"$group": {_id: {"type": "$type"}, total: {$sum: 1} }},{"$project":   {"type": "$_id.type", "tot": "$total", "_id": 0} }   )
```

It works as expected and returns,

```
{ "type" : "f", "tot" : 1 }
{ "type" : "ebm", "tot" : 1 }
{ "type" : "b", "tot" : 3 }
```

However, when I try replicating the pipeline in Golang, as follow:

```
    pipeline := []bson.M{
    // match
    {"$match": bson.M{"createdat": when}},
    // group
    {"$group": bson.M{
        "_id":        bson.M{"type": "$type"}, // "$fieldname" - return the field
        "TotalFeeds": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}},
    // project
    {"$project": bson.M{"type": "$_id.type", // project selects subset of fields
        "TotalFeeds": "$TotalFeeds", // rename fiedls
        "_id":        0}},           // 0 means not show _id
}
```

The returned count is 0.

```
map[$match:map[createdat:20190203]] map[$group:map[TotalFeeds:map[$sum:1] _id:map[type:$type]]] map[$project:map[type:$_id.type TotalFeeds:$TotalFeeds _id:0]]]
{f 0  }
{ebm 0  }
{b 0  }
[{f 0  } {ebm 0  } {b 0  }]
```

Below the entire function I am using in Golang:

```
func CountFeeds(when string) Feeds {

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 60*time.Second)

    pipeline := []bson.M{
        // match
        {"$match": bson.M{"createdat": when}},
        // group
        {"$group": bson.M{
            "_id":        bson.M{"type": "$type"}, // "$fieldname" - return the field
            "TotalFeeds": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}},
        // project
        {"$project": bson.M{"type": "$_id.type", // project select subset of fields
            "TotalFeeds": "$TotalFeeds", // rename fiedls
            "_id":        0}},           // 0 means not show _id
    }


    fmt.Println(pipeline)
    curs, err := db.Collection("feeds").Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
    utilities.Catch(err)

    defer curs.Close(ctx)

    element := Feeds{}
    e := []Feeds{}
    for curs.Next(ctx) {
        err := curs.Decode(&element)
        fmt.Println(element)
        utilities.Catch(err)
        e = append(e, element)
    }

    fmt.Println(e)
    return element
}
```

Comment: Just a quick remark, your comments " // match", " // group", are effectively useless since just below them the taken action is written. Unless you add some text to those comments describing what is happening, they are effectively useless.

Comment: Thanks! So insightful.. do you also know why it’s not working?

Comment: Since the grouping keys are clearly present in the output I'm suspect over possible type conversion from the original cursor. Pretty sure the `{ $sum: 1 }` gets internally treated as a `Double`, which means it's translation is probably coming through as floating point and possibly your numeric value in your struct is not lining up with that. So it's more likely happening there than the server suddenly deciding to send `0`.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I thought something in that direction too. So do you think var e struct{ type string, count float64} would work?

Comment: no luck. It's only working if a define a map[string]interface{}. Which is not ideal. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [bson.D{}](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) instead of [bson.M{}](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M). This is because `bson.D{}` should be used in situations where order matters, such as MongoDB commands.

You can also encapsulate the whole pipeline in [mongo.Pipeline](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Pipeline). For example:

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$match", bson.D{{"createdata", 10}}}},
    {{"$group", bson.D{
        {"_id",        bson.D{{"type", "$type"}}}, 
        {"TotalFeeds", bson.D{{"$sum", 1}}},
    }}},
    {{"$project", bson.D{
        {"type", "$_id.type"}, 
        {"TotalFeeds", "$TotalFeeds"}, 
        {"_id", 0}},
    }},          
}
```

Check your `Feeds{}` struct mapping. Make sure, either you specify the `bson` mapping, i.e. :

```
type Feeds struct {
    Type string `bson:"type"`
    TotalFeeds int `bson:"TotalFeeds"`
}
```

Or, in your projection stage `$project` you use consistent casing for the fields. For example, specify all lower case `type` and `totalfeeds` or all upper case `Type` and `TotalFeeds`.

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$match", bson.D{{"createdata", 10}}}},
    {{"$group", bson.D{
        {"_id",        bson.D{{"type", "$type"}}}, 
        {"totalfeeds", bson.D{{"$sum", 1}}},
    }}},
    {{"$project", bson.D{
        {"type", "$_id.type"}, 
        {"totalfeeds", "$totalfeeds"}, 
        {"_id", 0}},
    }},      
}
```

Then you don't have to specify the `bson` mapping in the struct:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Type string 
    Total int
}
```

So either use consistent field name cases in your struct, or explicitly provide the `bson` mapping.

Comment: Thanks! it really helped. I'll be using bson.D from now on. Re the data type, it worked with the right bson tag. However, I couldn't replicate your second method. Even if I use consistent names in the projection phase, I still need the the right tag in myStruct to have the data returned into Total.

One more question, why do I need the extra brackets when I use bson.D? i.e.
bson.D{ {"type", "$type} } rather than bson.D{"type", "$type"} and {{"$match", ..}} rather than {"$match", ..}?

Comment: Without seeing your struct I can't really comment on why the second method doesn't work for you. `bson.D{}` is like an array it's using commas, so you need to have another brackets to group the key/value. i.e. `bson.D{ {key, value}, {key2, value2} }`